# Viewfinder shaking in my sigma 18-200 lens with Canon eos1100d

Tags: focus, viewfinder

So, I dropped my camera yesterday wasn't a big drop and it was in its bag but today when I tried to use it the viewfinder has got an almost constant shake on it and all the photos are out of focus.

The shake sometimes disappears for an instant when I auto focus but starts again pretty quick.

I've swapped the lens for the canons original lens and theres no shaking so I can only assume the problem is with the lens. I'm travelling in central America so won't be able to take it to a sigma shop, and I'd like to avoid taking it to any old shop if I can.

Any ideas what might be up?

Comment: Does the shaking stop for as long as you half press the shutter button?

Answer (score 3):

You may have damaged the lens' OS system and it's allowing the floating elements to move freely now.

Comment: What is the OS system?

Comment: OS is the Optical Stabilization. Your lens is broken and will need to be repaired. In the mean time you could try turning off the OS system using the switch on the lens to see if the "shake" stops. If it does you can try using the lens without OS but you will need faster shutter speeds to stop any lens movements.